# MySQL overlaping time periods based on criteria

Tags: mysql

i am trying to write a query which would show me all records which overlap based on values Valid_From and Valid_To and based on criteria.

This is my sample data:

```
ID  |  Valid_From  |  Valid_To  |  Block_Type  |  Valid  |  Block_ID
1      5              10           a              TRUE      1
2      10             15           a              TRUE      1
3      6              10           a              TRUE      1
4      3              4            a              FALSE     1
5      2              4            a              FALSE     1
6      1              1            a              FALSE     1
7      1              10           b              TRUE      1
8      1              10           c              TRUE      2
9      1              10           c              TRUE      2
10     1              15           b              TRUE      1
11     5              10           a              TRUE      1
```

- ID is Primary Key with Auto Increment - unique for every record
- Block_Type - Type of block - can have more values for every Block_ID example: Block_ID 1 has Block_Type "a" and "b", Block_ID 2 has Block_Type "c", every Block_ID can have any Block_Type, meaning every Block_ID can have Block_Type "a" to "z"
- Valid - this just states if Valid_To is bigger than some value, for
  testing i set this value to 5
  Block_ID - groups multiple records in one Group

For showing what records overlap i use this query:

```
select a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) as abcd
from new_table a, new_table b
where a.id <> b.id
and a.Block_ID = b.Block_ID
and a.Block_Type = b.Block_Type
and a.Valid = b.Valid
and ((a.Valid_To between b.Valid_From and b.Valid_To) or (a.Valid_From between b.Valid_From and b.Valid_To)
or (a.Valid_To = b.Valid_From) or (a.Valid_From = b.Valid_To))
group by a.id;
```

this works fine, it shows me if any records with same Block_Type, same value in Valid and Block_ID overlap, my problem is that this query doesnt show me records which dont overlap (in this example it is record with ID 6) i completely understand why, so i tried to edit my query using case when instead of where but so far i wasnt able to achieve what i want.

This is what my query returns now:

```
ID  |  abcd
1      2
2      1,11,3
3      2
4      5
5      4
7      10
8      9
9      8
10     7
11     2
```

I would like this query to list all records and to list in new column "abcd" all overlaping records, for records that do not overlap i would just like null in the same column, so it would look like this:

```
ID  |  abcd
1      2
2      1,11,3
3      2
4      5
5      4
6      null
7      10
8      9
9      8
10     7
11     2
```

cant you point me in the right direction? What can i change to make it work the way i need?

Thank you very much

Comment: ? Your result set doesn't match your data set !?"?"?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, i am sorry, what do you mean? I would be extremely happy if you find any errors in my code, so i can practice more :)

Comment: Your query does not return that result set.

Comment: aha, for me it does, if we talk about the third code block

Comment: I cannot replicate this result. If you're satisfied with the existing answer (which seems unnecessarily verbose to me), then fine. Otherwise, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thank you very much for the advice, i will certainly look into it as i am trying to get better in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, You need a left join instead of Inner join -

```
SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS abcd
FROM new_table a
LEFT JOIN new_table b ON a.id <> b.id
                      AND a.Block_ID = b.Block_ID
                      AND a.Block_Type = b.Block_Type
                      AND a.Valid = b.Valid
                      AND ((a.Valid_To BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                            OR (a.Valid_From BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                            OR (a.Valid_To = b.Valid_From)
                            OR (a.Valid_From = b.Valid_To)
                          )
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: Hello Ankit, thank you very much for your comment, your code unfortunately returns same result :(, i still dont see records with ID 6 for some reason.

Comment: @Raymond_90, Can you please give it a try now?

Comment: You are great :) just by changing where to and it works :) Thank you very much, ill accept your answer as solution

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you. Your'e always welcome.

Comment: There appears to be more query here than is strictly necessary.