# MySQL update based on query result

Tags: mysql

i hope this is not considered spamming, today i asked a question:

[MySQL overlaping time periods based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289060/mysql-overlaping-time-periods-based-on-criteria)

now i am trying to do an update query, based on this query:

```
SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS abcd
FROM new_table a
LEFT JOIN new_table b ON a.id <> b.id
                      AND a.Block_ID = b.Block_ID
                      AND a.Block_Type = b.Block_Type
                      AND a.Valid = b.Valid
                      AND ((a.Valid_To BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                            OR (a.Valid_From BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                            OR (a.Valid_To = b.Valid_From)
                            OR (a.Valid_From = b.Valid_To)
                          )
GROUP BY a.id;
```

i am trying to update this table:

```
ID  |  Valid_From  |  Valid_To  |  Block_Type  |  Valid  |  Block_ID
1      5              10           a              TRUE      1
2      10             15           a              TRUE      1
3      6              10           a              TRUE      1
4      3              4            a              FALSE     1
5      2              4            a              FALSE     1
6      1              1            a              FALSE     1
7      1              10           b              TRUE      1
8      1              10           c              TRUE      2
9      1              10           c              TRUE      2
10     1              15           b              TRUE      1
11     5              10           a              TRUE      1
```

for my data set, this query returs this:

```
ID  |  abcd
1      2
2      1,11,3
3      2
4      5
5      4
6      null
7      10
8      9
9      8
10     7
11     2
```

i inserted new column in my table using

```
ALTER TABLE new_table
ADD COLUMN `Overlaping` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `Block_ID`;
```

Now i am trying to populate this column using this query, where i would like to update value to 'overlaping' for records where column abcd is not null:

```
UPDATE new_table nt2,
(SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS abcd
FROM new_table a
LEFT JOIN new_table b ON a.id <> b.id
                      AND a.Block_ID = b.Block_ID
                      AND a.Block_Type = b.Block_Type
                      AND a.Valid = b.Valid
                      AND ((a.Valid_To BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                            OR (a.Valid_From BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                            OR (a.Valid_To = b.Valid_From)
                            OR (a.Valid_From = b.Valid_To)
                          )
GROUP BY a.id) as ac
SET nt2.Overlaping = 'overlaping'
where ac.abcd is not null;
```

however this query updates every single row no matter if abcd is null or not, where is the mistake?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inner  Join the original table and the new Select

```
UPDATE new_table nt2 Left join
  (SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS abcd
   FROM new_table a
     inner JOIN new_table b ON a.id <> b.id
                  AND a.Block_ID = b.Block_ID
                  AND a.Block_Type = b.Block_Type
                  AND a.Valid = b.Valid
                  AND ((a.Valid_To BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                        OR (a.Valid_From BETWEEN b.Valid_From AND b.Valid_To)
                        OR (a.Valid_To = b.Valid_From)
                        OR (a.Valid_From = b.Valid_To)
                      )
                GROUP BY a.id) as ac 
   on ac.id = nt.id
SET nt2.Overlaping = ac.abcd
where ac.abcd is not null;
```